# What a good app to tag my favorite places?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation

I travel a lot to the same 5 cities for work. Sometimes, if I have a spare hour or two I explore and sometimes on those explorations, I find great places. I'd like to tag those places on a map with an iphone app. But google map app doesn't allow that. I can't find software for this.

Comment: FourSquare is a good one?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps does indeed allow this.

1. Find the place you want.
2. Bring up the details for that location by tapping on it, either in search results or the box at the bottom of the screen after you have selected a place.
3. Tap the Save icon (between Call and Website, highlighted in the screenshot).

These places are included when searching going forward, as well as displayed on the map view with gold stars when you are sufficiently zoomed in.

You can also view an overall list of them by tapping the [image: Google hamburger menu icon] menu, selecting Your Places and scrolling to find your Saved Places.

[image: Google Maps screenshot]

Comment: Thanks - but it just saves as a gold star - I can't even show what it was, be it a bar, restaurant, cafe or whathaveyou.

Comment: Tap on it like you would any other location on the map and it will show details.